# Adding constructor details to Unity config

Tags: c#, unity-container

How we can specify multiple constructors in Unity config file. if class is implemented something like below:

```
 public abstract class classB : ClassA
{

private classC c;
protected ClassB()
    {
        c = new classC();

    }

    protected classB(classC value)
{
        c = value;

    }
 }
```

And in Unity config file we can specify something like this.

```
<type name="ClassB" type="ClassB">
      <lifetime type="PerWebRequest" />
      <typeConfig extensionType="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.TypeInjectionElement, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration">
        <constructor>
        </constructor>
      </typeConfig>
    </type>
```

But here how to specify another constructor and also assigning values to the property in case of default constructor?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure this element only specifies a specific constructor (One) to be called when you have multiple constructors.
See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660914%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx)

I guess this is similar to the programmatic approach - [InjectionConstructor] where you tell Unity to use the constructor that is specified with the attribute.